# Leap motion -> Node.js -> Arduino. Error: SerialPort not open

Tags: node.js, arduino, leap-motion

I've been trying to connect my leap with my arduino using node.js, following [this guide](http://xseignard.github.io/2013/06/25/interfacing-leap-motion-with-arduino-thanks-to-nodejs/), but I keep getting this error:

```
1442170022060 Device(s) /dev/cu.usbmodem1421  
1442170022073 Connected /dev/cu.usbmodem1421  
1442170025540 Repl Initialized  
>> events.js:85
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
Error: Serialport not open.
    at SerialPortFactory.SerialPort.write (/Users/Kenny/Documents/src/node_modules/johnny-five/node_modules/serialport/serialport.js:288:17)
    at Board.analogWrite (/Users/Kenny/Documents/src/node_modules/johnny-five/node_modules/firmata/lib/firmata.js:643:18)
    at Board.servoWrite (/Users/Kenny/Documents/src/node_modules/johnny-five/node_modules/firmata/lib/firmata.js:690:20)
    at Servo.Controllers.Standard.servoWrite.value (/Users/Kenny/Documents/src/node_modules/johnny-five/lib/servo.js:108:17)
    at Servo.to (/Users/Kenny/Documents/src/node_modules/johnny-five/lib/servo.js:315:12)
    at Object._move [as move] (/Users/Kenny/Documents/src/lib/joint.js:28:10)
    at WebSocket.<anonymous> (/Users/Kenny/Documents/src/proj.js:41:26)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Receiver.ontext (/Users/Kenny/Documents/src/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:816:10)
    at /Users/Kenny/Documents/src/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:477:18
```

This is my code

```
var five = require('johnny-five'),
WebSocket = require('ws'),
ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:6437'),
board = new five.Board(),
LeapFrame = require('./lib/leapFrame'),
Joint = require('./lib/joint'),
frame,
i = 0;
```

board.on('ready',function() {

```
     var servoPitch = new Joint({

        minPos: 50,
        maxPos: 100,
        pin: 11,
        range: [70,100]
     });

     var servoNod = new Joint({
        minPos: 0,
        maxPos: 100,
        pin: 10,
        range: [70, 130]
     })

     var servoRoll = new Joint({
        minPos: -60,
        maxPos: 430,
        pin: 9,
        range: [0,200]
     })

     ws.on('message',function(data,flags) {
           i++;
           if (i%3 == 0) {
            frame = new LeapFrame(data);
            if(frame.valid) {
            servoPitch.move(frame.deltaHandFinger.y);
           servoRoll.move(200 - frame.palmPosition.x);
           servoNod.move(frame.palmPosition.y);

            }
           i = 0;
           }
           });



     });
```

I uploaded standardfirmata onto my arduino

im able to use servoRoll fine, but the other two are giving me the error

Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Can you provide more informations about your problem ? Such as your code. In order to help others to help you.

Comment: Were you able to get the basic LED code working?  Are you on Windows, Mac, or Linux?  What does the code look like which caused this error?  Did you load StandardFirmata on the Arduino?

Comment: Yes, I was able to get the LED code to work. Im working on a mac and I just uploaded the code I used